# Can client set LastVerbExecuted when replied to an email?

Tags: windows-runtime, exchange-server, activesync

My client uses Exchange Active Sync (EAS) to communicate with the exchange server. When I reply to an email (SendMail), I do not get the correct LastVerbExecuted parameter from the server. My question is, is client supposed to set this field and send it as a part of the Change command or server should do that for me?

Just to add, when OWA is used to reply to some email, it seems to have set the LastVerbExecuted just fine on the server. However, when I sent an email from my client it does not seem to be working and the server does not send the LastVerbExecuted as 'ReplyToSender'.

Can anyone help me discover the issue?

Edit: I suppose the problem is with my client not sending any element in SendMail command request which will help the server to identify which email is being responded to. So now my actual question is, which element can be used in SendMail command to send the identity of the actual email (which is replied to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get it confirmed from microsoft that lastverbexecuted is only available with SmartReply and SmartForward commands:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0fab280-0036-40f4-830a-00c748573f7f/lastverbexecuted-when-using-smartreply-with-exchange-2010-is-wrong?forum=os_exchangeprotocols

Quote from the article:
"We have concluded our investigation in to this issue and it has been determined that the LastVerbExecuted element will ONLY be updated with the use of the SmartReply and SmartForward commands. There is not currently a way to use the SendMail command and have it update the LastVerbExecuted."